# Is there a way to combine these sklearn Pipelines/ColumnTransformers so I don't have to make multiple fit_transform() calls?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I'd like to create a Pipeline where I can call `fit_transform()` just *one* time on my train dataset (train_df) and receive a fully preprocessed dataset. I don't think I can currently do that, however, because I have to call PCA() on the output of a ColumnTransformer and then concatenate *that* output with the result of a separate ColumnTransformer called on train_df. Basically, I think I'm going too high up the abstraction ladder, with one too many pipelines/ct's embedded within each other. There's no way to streamline the entire preprocessing process by passing train_df to a single Pipeline or ColumnTransformer - unless I'm missing something and you have any insight? I've spent hours wracking myself around this problem and have finally faced the reality I'm just spinning my wheels. Any help or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
num_ct = ColumnTransformer([
                        ('non_skewed_num', non_skewed_num_pipe, non_skewed_vars),
                        ('skewed_num', skewed_num_pipe, skewed_vars)
                        ], remainder='drop')

total_num_pipe = Pipeline([('num_ct', num_ct), 
                           ('dim_reduc', PCA(n_components=5))])


cat_ct = ColumnTransformer([
                        ('cat_pipe1', cat_pipe1, cat_vars1),
                        ('cat_pipe2', cat_pipe2, cat_vars2)
                        ], remainder='drop')


final_num = total_num_pipe.fit_transform(train_df)
final_cat = cat_ct.fit_transform(train_df)
final_X_train = np.c_[final_num, final_cat]
```

Comment: `ColumnTransformer` can be a pipeline step, and if you only want to apply it on certain columns you can use the `remainder="passthrough"` parameter. Maybe rework this into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thank you so much -- that's a combination I did not consider, and ultimately it led me to a solution that got the job done. One important thing that's worth emphasizing is that the ColumnTransformers occurring later in the Pipeline might need column *indices* instead of column names (from a df), since earlier ColumnTransformers will spit out a NumPy array (at least prior to sklearn version 1.2). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to this, thanks to @Alexander's suggestion of chaining ColumnTransformers into a Pipeline. (TLDR: Don't forget that you can create a Pipeline of ColumnTransformers, using remainder='passthrough' to your advantage.)

I first created a ColumnTransformer that concatenates the transformations for both numeric *and* categorical variables, but without the PCA.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([
                        ('non_skewed_num', non_skewed_num_pipe, non_skewed_vars),
                        ('skewed_num', skewed_num_pipe, skewed_vars),
                        ('cat_pipe1', cat_pipe1, cat_vars1),
                        ('cat_pipe2', cat_pipe2, cat_vars2)
                        ], remainder='drop')
```

Then, I created a `ColumnTransformer` *just* for the PCA, and when I specified which columns to apply this to, I used a slice object since this `ColumnTransformer` will be fed a NumPy array--not a DataFrame--in the eventual Pipeline (it will be the second `ColumnTransformer` in the Pipeline). I also set remainder='passthrough' so the non-numeric variables will be retained untransformed after the PCA.

```
ct2 = ColumnTransformer([('dim_reduc', PCA(n_components=5), slice(0, 37))], remainder='passthrough')  # 37 is number of numeric variables
```

Finally, I created a Pipeline chaining these two `ColumnTransformers`

```
final_pipe = Pipeline([('ct', ct), 
                       ('ct2', ct2)])
```

Calling `final_pipe.fit_transform(train_df)` yields the cleaned array I wanted. Hope this helps!